# About Central-by-finite subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a torsion group and $H \unlhd G$. Suppose that $H$ is a locally finite group and suppose that $H$ let be a FC-group.

Let $x \in G$. Then is true that $[H,x]$ is a central-by-finite group?

Notations:

1) FC-group: $G$ is said FC-group if for all $x \in G$ is true that the set $x^G$ is finite; or equivalently $|G:C_G(x)|$ is finite for all $x \in G$;

2) Central-by-finite: A group $G$ is said central-by-finite if if your center has finite index.

Answer (score 5):

Let $H = \times_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ be a direct product of countably many copies of a finite nonabelian group $X$, Take $G=H \rtimes C_2$, where $C_2 = \langle x \rangle$ acts on $H$ by permuting the copies $X_i$of $X$ with the permutation $(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)\cdots$. Then $[H,x]$ contains a direct product of infinitely many copies of $X$ and so is not central-by-finite.